OIDC logging for the open id
Based on my last question which was Using openid-connect access token and getting 403 in postman and 401 in logs I enabled some more login:
19 Jul 16:46:11 DEBUG  [context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] - Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken [Principal=x, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@42110557, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_AUTHENTICATED, ADMINISTRATOR, AUTHENTICATED, ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR, ROLE_STAFF]]] to HttpSession [Session@78a58f49{id=node0wg09rz0u6lbt10ajn14meo8ga2,x=node0wg09rz0u6lbt10ajn14meo8ga2.node0,req=1,res=true}]
19 Jul 16:46:17 DEBUG  [web.FilterChainProxy] - Securing GET /rest/security/roles
19 Jul 16:46:17 DEBUG  [client.RestTemplate] - HTTP GET http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
19 Jul 16:46:17 DEBUG  [client.RestTemplate] - Accept=[application/xml, text/xml, application/json, application/*+xml, application/*+json]
19 Jul 16:46:17 DEBUG  [client.RestTemplate] - Writing [{}] with org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter
19 Jul 16:46:17 DEBUG  [client.RestTemplate] - Response 401 UNAUTHORIZED
19 Jul 16:46:17 ERROR  [geoserver.security] - Oauth2 OIDC - an error occurred during token validation.  Most likely the token has expired or is invalid/modified.  401 Unauthorized: "{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Token verification failed"}"
19 Jul 16:46:17 DEBUG  [savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache] - Saved request http://localhost:8081/geoserver/rest/security/roles to session
19 Jul 16:46:17 DEBUG  [authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint] - Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
19 Jul 16:46:17 DEBUG  [context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] - Removed SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication] from HttpSession [Session@41508786{id=node0ck3w8py5uhrvq8xtub7p69wq3,x=node0ck3w8py5uhrvq8xtub7p69wq3.node0,req=1,res=true}]
19 Jul 16:46:48 DEBUG  [web.FilterChainProxy] - Securing GET /rest/security/roles
19 Jul 16:46:48 DEBUG  [client.RestTemplate] - HTTP GET http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
19 Jul 16:46:48 DEBUG  [client.RestTemplate] - Accept=[application/xml, text/xml, application/json, application/*+xml, application/*+json]
19 Jul 16:46:48 DEBUG  [client.RestTemplate] - Writing [{}] with org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter
19 Jul 16:46:48 DEBUG  [client.RestTemplate] - Response 200 OK
19 Jul 16:46:48 DEBUG  [client.RestTemplate] - Reading to [java.util.Map<?, ?>]
19 Jul 16:46:48 DEBUG  [security.oauth2] - OIDC: Getting Roles from AccessToken, location=roles
19 Jul 16:46:48 DEBUG  [path.CompiledPath] - Evaluating path: $['roles']
19 Jul 16:46:48 DEBUG  [security.oauth2] - Did not find roles in the token, returning an empty role list
19 Jul 16:46:48 DEBUG  [security.oauth2] - OIDC: roles returned NO ROLES
19 Jul 16:46:48 DEBUG  [intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor] - Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /rest/security/roles] with attributes [ADMIN]
19 Jul 16:46:48 DEBUG  [access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl] - Responding with 403 status code
19 Jul 16:46:48 DEBUG  [context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] - Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken [Principal=x@x.com, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1], SessionId=node0ck3w8py5uhrvq8xtub7p69wq3], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_AUTHENTICATED]]] to HttpSession [Session@41508786{id=node0ck3w8py5uhrvq8xtub7p69wq3,x=node0ck3w8py5uhrvq8xtub7p69wq3.node0,req=1,res=true}]

This is the decoded jwt:
{
  "exp": 1721288477,
  "iat": 1721288417,
  "jti": "c54b0edb-bc88-4b64-9a7e-a70424d90f47",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/realms/master",
  "aud": [
    "master-realm",
    "account"
  ],
  "sub": "c2250bd0-596a-4eb1-a774-815c77f90efc",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "geoserver-client",
  "session_state": "5f5afaff-c680-44eb-9a80-082ab028e4ea",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "create-realm",
      "default-roles-master",
      "offline_access",
      "admin",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "geoserver-client": {
      "roles": [
        "ADMINISTRATOR",
        "ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"
      ]
    },
    "master-realm": {
      "roles": [
        "view-identity-providers",
        "view-realm",
        "manage-identity-providers",
        "impersonation",
        "create-client",
        "manage-users",
        "query-realms",
        "view-authorization",
        "query-clients",
        "query-users",
        "manage-events",
        "manage-realm",
        "view-events",
        "view-users",
        "view-clients",
        "manage-authorization",
        "manage-clients",
        "query-groups"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "sid": "5f5afaff-c680-44eb-9a80-082ab028e4ea",
  "email_verified": true,
  "preferred_username": "x",
  
}

This is the open id filter page:

Am I missing authentication provider here? Its been long banging my head against the wall. I'm new to geoserver hence not sure if I'm looking at the right place. When I hit http://localhost:8081/geoserver/rest/security/roles in postman with bearer token I am greeted with:
{
"servlet": "dispatcher",
"message": "Forbidden",
"url": "/geoserver/rest/security/roles",
"status": "403"
}

I think you need to add "resource_access.geoserver-client.roles" instead of only "roles".
